# How to read many.dat files of the same directory and treat them as listsor arrays in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have many  2-column.dat files in a directory and i  want to find the maximum of each column of each file and append them to new lists.

i have tried the following but I think that i can;t treat the .dat files' content like numbers.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import glob   
import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

MAX=[]
path = 'directory_path/*dat'   
os.chdir("directory_path/*dat")
for file in glob.glob("*.dat"):
   print(file)
    a,b,x,y=np.loadtxt(file,unpack=True)
   X=x.tolist()
   print np.max(X)
#    print('processing'),file
#    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.title(file)
#    MAX.append(np.max(y))
#    plt.show()
```

I can plot each file separately, but the erro i get is a plain ''invalid syntax'' and the "       print np.max(X)" is highlighted.

Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `import print_function`, you've told Python that `print` is a function, **not** a statement -- so of course you must call it as `print(np.max(X))` to get rid of the syntax error.  You've used `(...)` after other `print`s in your code (live and commented-out), just for some mysterious reason not after that one.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex! After your answer I saw what " import print_function" does.It's all clear now, thank you very much.

Comment: @astromath, always glad to help, but remember: if my answer was helpful you could **accept** it.